# Scheduling jupyter notebook runs across devices

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a large number of jupyter notebooks that I run to collect data on a daily, weekly and monthly basis. They output csv files which are saved to iCloud.

At the moment I am scheduling those to run automatically with Soma Zone’s LaunchControl.

That works well, but it has two disadvantages:

1. I have to convert the notebooks to py files to allow them to run automatically.
2. I can’t synch LaunchControl across devices. If I am away and my desktop goes offline, the automatic updates stop. I could of course repeat the LaunchControl settings on my laptop, but that isn’t ideal.

Is there a better solution that solves both these issues, and that runs without the jupyter notebooks necessarily being open? I’ve looked around at Mercury and others, but can’t figure out what might work.

Comment: Have you checked out [Jupyter Scheduler](https://blog.jupyter.org/introducing-jupyter-scheduler-f9e82676c388)? Or [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/index.html) recommended in [this blog post](https://netflixtechblog.com/scheduling-notebooks-348e6c14cfd6) by Netflix this is several years old now?

Comment: @Wayne I tried Jupyter Scheduler, but 1) when I set up a schedule for a notebook on a desktop, it didn’t show when opening the same notebook on a notebook and 2) it didn’t run when jupyter lab was closed. I think Jupyter Scheduler should be able to do both, but I haven’t worked out how.

Comment: Yes, maybe since it is internal it has to be open for it to run. What about just using chron jobs to combine with running the notebooks from the command line via `jupyter nbconvert` or `jupytext`? Jupytext has commands that execute notebooks on the command line without needing to convert them to scripts.